# Adding a temporary NavigationController to the root view

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I working on the push notification handling for my application. When opening the application from a notification I want to "push" a new view controller with the relevant content.

My root controller is TabBarController, so can´t use that.

I guess one solution is to add a navigation controller to my root and then use that to push to the new controller.

Is this a recommended way to do this or is there a best practice for here?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will do what you are looking to do. However you will need to somehow allow the user no dismiss this ViewController to return to the regular UI.

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
      UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];

     if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive || state == UIApplicationStateBackground) {

          YourViewController *vc = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
          [self.window addSubview:vc.view];

          [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
     } 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but that will result in a modal presentation, I´m trying to  "push" it.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean in that case. You can simply embed it into a NavigationViewController. Do you mean that when pressing back you can return to the RootViewController? Maybe a diagram would help.